# Access Netsuite xml attribute suitescript

Tags: xml, netsuite, suitescript

When veiwing any record in Netsuite you can add the following parmameter "&xml=t" to the URL and see th XML data of the record.  Sometimes there is data in the xml that is not exposed to any field and I am looking for a way to access it with suitescript but so far I have struck out.  Here is an snippet of a vendor credit:

```
`<line>
<amount>26.10</amount>
<apply>T</apply>
<applydate>1/28/2016</applydate>
<doc>400620</doc>
<due>26.10</due>
<duedate>1/28/2016</duedate>
<internalid>400620</internalid>
<line>0</line>
<pymt>401604</pymt>`
```

How would I pull the `<pymt>401604</pymt>` attribute using suitescript as this is the id of a payment record and is not exposed to the UI and I has no internalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the `apply` sublist.  It's possible the data isn't visible on the form you're using.

Try this:

```
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('vendorcredit',recid)
var firstLinePayment = rec.getLineItemValue('apply','pymt',1)
```

That should give you the transaction id for the record that line applied to.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I made the wrong assumption that if the field was not listed in the Netsuite record browser that I could not use it.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in Sandbox but it still works in Production.  Not sure what is going on here but since 'pymt' is not defined in the record browser it may no longer work?  Can anyone else tell me if they are experiencing the same results?

Comment: Looks like it's maybe:

`var firstLinePayment = rec.getLineItemValue('apply','amount',1)`